# Docker build failing with the potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace error

Tags: docker, build, rocky-os

Docker build failing with the following error in a rocky 8 instance
Error: creating build container: copying system image from manifest list: writing blob: adding layer with blob "sha256:*********": processing tar file(potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:42 for /etc/shadow): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid if configured locally and run podman-system-migrate: lchown /etc/shadow: invalid argument): exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add the particular user under which build was being run to the files /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid and restarting docker process.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo usermod --add-subuids 10000-75535 $(whoami)
sudo usermod --add-subgids 10000-75535 $(whoami)

sudo echo "$(whoami):10000:65536" >> /etc/subuid
sudo echo "$(whoami):10000:65536" >> /etc/subgid
```

[Rootless mode](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman.1.html#rootless-mode) by podman doc.